# shortcut to type https:// for me?

Tags: google-chrome, https

So, we haven't had to type http:// since 1997 or so, but we still have to type https:// unless the website has setup a redirection.

There's macros/textexpander/bookmark for overcoming the agonizing 8 seconds this takes. Anything else? Anything builtin to the browser?

Comment: there is extension. https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere

Comment: Try this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-text-expander-for-go/iibninhmiggehlcdolcilmhacighjamp?hl=en  may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use extensions like [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/Https-everywhere) (which was built by the EFF) or similar extensions.

HTTPS Everywhere uses a whitelist of sites that have good HTTPS support, so it doesn't force every page you visit to be HTTPS. Still a very helpful extension.

Comment: Yes, it even works on the SE network, which we all know doesn't yet fully support https ...